# Adobe Edge slideshow back button

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

I have created a slideshow using Edge Animate and it has a set of selected pictures (number of pictures wont increase for now) and they change automatically after 5 seconds. The slideshow also includes two buttons: Next and Back. The next button works fine, it has the following code:

```
sym.play();
```

Simple as that. I thought that sym.playReverse(); would solve my problem for the back button, but it didn't. It just goes back to the previous pic and stays there for not even a second and then goes forward again. I want to delay this back button to the normal delay time which is 5 seconds. So when someone clicks back, he gets to the previous picture and stays there for 5 seconds.

Just for reference purposes, here is my code that automatically "slides" the pictures after 5 seconds automatically:

```
sym.stop();
setTimeout(function(){sym.play();},5500);
```

Each picture (label-ed) has this code.

So how do I make my back button work as it should?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `sym.play()`, but specify a parameter.
the parameter should be in milliseconds, which you already seem to understand.

so you might have something like:

```
sym.play(3000)
sym.stop();
setTimeout(function(){sym.play();},5500);
```

that would take your animation back to the previous slide, assuming it's at 3 seconds on your timeline, then your automatic sliding would kick in again.

just comment if you have more questions.
hope this helps.